# List other installed apps like the Workflow app

Tags: ios, url-scheme

The [Workflow](http://workflow.is) app for iOS lists all other installed apps and can open any one of them without predefined URL schemes!

How can my app do that?

Comment: What makes you think they're not using URL schemes?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I didn’t said they are not using schemes , but schemes are not predefined with the workflow bundle... is there a way to list all available schemes?

Comment: They're not listed in the Info.plist, you mean? I don't know how they would get around that, unless they got special dispensation now that they're owned by Apple.